# react typescript I get data from context it's valid but i can not map through it i get undefined error

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am having trouble with react typescript. Whenever I got to url I trigger context function which fetches data when data is fetched i am setting state and whenever it's set i am passing it to another component and trying to ma. but I get undefined cannot map error
but indeed I have data. I think its typescript thing because I had no problem doing following in javascript
here is picturesenter image description here[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { IMeal } from '../../_types/contexType'
import styles from './CategoryGallery.module.scss'

interface props {
  meals: IMeal[]
}

function CategoryGallery({meals}:props) {

  if(!meals) return <h1>Loading ...</h1>

  console.log(meals)
  return (
    <div className={styles.gallery}>

      {meals.map((x,i) => {
        const {strMeal,strMealThumb} = x;
        return (
          <figure className={`${styles.gallery__item} ${styles.gallery__item__[i]}`}>
            <img src={strMealThumb} alt={strMeal}/>
            <h6 className={styles.gallery__item__heading}>{strMeal}</h6>
          </figure>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CategoryGallery
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import CategoryFilter from '../../components/CategoryFiler/CategoryFilter';
import CategoryGallery from '../../components/CategoryGallery/CategoryGallery';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../context';
import styles from './SingleRCategory.module.scss';

function SingleRCategory() {
  const {categoryname} = useParams<{categoryname?:string}>();

  const {byCategory,category} =  useGlobalContext()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(byCategory){
      if(!categoryname) return;
      byCategory(categoryname)
      
    }

  },[categoryname,category])

 


  const getCategoryTheme = ()=> {
    const Theme = new Map([
      ["meat","meatTheme"],
      ["vegie","vegieTheme"],
      ["seaFood","seaFoodTheme"],
    ]);
    if(categoryname){
      const selectedItem = Theme.get(categoryname);
      if(!selectedItem) return "";
      return selectedItem;
    }
    return "";

  }
  
  
  return (
   <div className={`${styles.singleRcCategory} ${styles[getCategoryTheme()]}`}>
      {category &&  <CategoryFilter meals={category}/>}
      {category && <CategoryGallery meals={category}/>}
      
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleRCategory
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IMealsContext,IFeatured,IMeal,IntroFood,  } from "./_types/contexType";


export const AppContext = createContext<Partial<IMealsContext>>({});

export type AppProviderProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export function AppProvider({children}: AppProviderProps){
    const [category,setCategory] = useState<IMeal[]>();
    const [singleMeal,setSingleMeal] = useState<IMeal>();
    const [sortedMeal,setSortedMeal] = useState<IMeal[]>();
    const [favoriteMeals,setFavoriteMeals] = useState<IMeal[]>();

    const [introFood,setIntroFood] = useState<IntroFood[]>();
    const [featured,setFeatured] = useState<IMeal[]>();

    const dataFetcher = async (arr: string[]) => {
        const data= await Promise.all(arr.map(async (x) => {

            const meal = await fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=${x}`);
            const data = await meal.json();
            return data;
        }));
        const flattend: IMeal[] = data.flatMap((x) => x.meals);
        return flattend;
    }



    
    const forIntro = () => {
        fetch("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=h")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => data.meals)
        .then((data:IMeal[]) => {
            
            return data.slice(1,3).map(x => {
                const {strMeal,strMealThumb,strIngredient1,
                strIngredient2,strIngredient3,strIngredient4} = x;

                let ingredients;
                const rating = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10).toString();
                ingredients = [strIngredient1,strIngredient2,strIngredient3,strIngredient4];
                const result:IntroFood  = {
                    img:strMealThumb,
                    name:strMeal,
                    rating:rating,
                    ingredients
                }
                return result;
                
            })
        })
        .then((result) => setIntroFood(result))
        
                
                
    }

    const mealMap = new Map([
        ["meat",["Beef","Chicken","Goat","Lamp","Pork"]],
        ["vegie",["Vegan","Vegetarian"]],
        ["seaFood",["Seafood"]]
    ])

    const byCategory =  (category: string) => {
        const selectedCategory = mealMap.get(category);
        if(selectedCategory)
            dataFetcher(selectedCategory).then(res => setCategory(res));
        


    }


    const forFeature = async () => {
        const letters = ["a","h","d"];
        const data= await Promise.all(letters.map(async (x) => {
            const meal = await fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=${x}`);
            const data = await meal.json();
            return data;
        }));
        
        const flattend: IMeal[] = data.flatMap((x) => x.meals);
        setFavoriteMeals(flattend.slice(2));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        forIntro()
    },[])


    return <AppContext.Provider value={{category,singleMeal,
    introFood,byCategory,forFeature,favoriteMeals}}>
        {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
    return useContext(AppContext)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not images. Also, please post a [mcve] of the issue

Comment: provided context and components code